# To have notes and move them super-easy over canvas

Tags: windows, note-taking, knowledge-organization, mind-mapping, dashboard

I am looking for a lightweight software for easy manipulation, changing and "**moving**" of the notes. Important is easy positioning of the notes inside some "notes area".

Think, for example, about the MS Excel and its cells:

- so adding note to the cell, changing colour, copy the cell and similar operations would be as easy as in Excel
- moving cell from one position to another position would be more easy, than in Excel (in Excel it is not possible to simply grip the cell by its centre and drag it - one must hit the border by mouse pointer and futhermore, after moving of the cell, there is a problem with borders - if you had made borders between cells, then by the moving of the cells, the mesh of cell borders is beeing destroyed)
- the Excell cell do not support more lines made by Enter and similar things

So, software, I would like to find, would manage rectangles with notes, similarly like **real** Post-it stickers. But apparently **different way**, than the most today's stickers software implementations on market.

It would be used for cognated goals, as the other "notes processing" software - but apparently different way.

System requirements: Windows 7 (in any case offline piece of software)

Have tried from time to time some pieces of interesting software (some PIMs, Evernote, and others), but no of them did, what I described in this question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might like the [iMapping Tool](http://www.imapping.info).
It is basically an infinite canvas where you can put, interlink and move notes.
The special thing about iMapping is that every note is like a canvas itself and can hold other notes. Like that, you can build large zoomable knowledge maps with thousands of notes if necessary.

The website is in German, while the tool itself is English. Just check out the video - you will get an impression.

Support is availlable in English, German and French at support@imapping.info

Disclaimer: The iMapping Tool is my own development. I sell it commercially. There is a [free version availabe for download though](http://www.imapping.info/download/).